# Changed Package Name in Android Project, Now nothing works and it returns a null pointer error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I changed the package name of an Android Project using the Refactor in Eclipse, and after this my project would compile and run on my phone in Eclipse. However, when I exported it as a .apk file it no longer worked and always immediately crashed.

This is the error that it returns when it crashes:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper.AudioWallpaperService: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2556)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper.AudioWallpaperService.<init>(AudioWallpaperService.java:37)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2553)
 ... 10 more
```

This is my java class:

```
package com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord ;
import android.media.AudioFormat ; 
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;


public class AudioWallpaperService extends WallpaperService 
{


            public AudioWallpaperService() {
                super() ;

            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate()
            {
                    super.onCreate();  

                    colordelemiter = 255/800 ;

                    exagger = (float) 0.08;

                    defaultRaduiis = 850 ;
                    on = pastRadii.size()-1 ;
                    colorMult = 20;
                    circleNum   = 8;
            }


            static int bufferSize  ; 

            static AudioRecord recorder ;

            static  ArrayList<float[]> pastRadii ;

            static  float cosValues[] ;
            static  float sinValues[] ;
            static ArrayList<Integer> circleEmphasis ;
            static float scalarValues[] ;
            static float scalarValuesNEXT[] ;
            static Paint p ;
            static int circleNum ;

            static int colorMult ;
            static  int on ;

            static float colordelemiter ;

            static boolean firstdraw = true; 

            static   int defaultRaduiis ;
            static    float exagger ;

            static     int centerX  ;
            static    int centerY ;
            static  int width;
              static int size ;
            static   int height;

            static float[] radiiMaxValues;

             public static void releaseAudio() {
                  if (recorder != null) {
                  recorder.stop() ;
                  recorder.release() ;
                  recorder = null ;
                  }
              }

              public static void captureAudio() {     
                  if (recorder == null) {
                 bufferSize  =          AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);           
                 recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize*10);  
                      recorder.startRecording();
                  }
              }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() 
            {
                    super.onDestroy();


            }
            @Override
            public Engine onCreateEngine() 
            {    
                    return new AudioWallpaperEngine();

            }

             class AudioWallpaperEngine extends Engine 
            {

                    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            draw();
                        }
                    };
                    private boolean visible = true;


                    AudioWallpaperEngine() 
                    {


                        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) ;
                        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);


                            bufferSize  = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);           
                            recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize*10);  
                            pastRadii = new ArrayList<float[]>() ;  

                            recorder.startRecording();
                            radiiMaxValues = new float[bufferSize/4] ;
                            float deltaAngle = (float) (8*Math.PI/ bufferSize) ;

                            size = (bufferSize - 1)/4;

                        circleEmphasis = new ArrayList<Integer> () ;
                        scalarValues = new float[circleNum] ;

                        scalarValuesNEXT =  new float[circleNum] ;
                        for (int i = circleNum-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
                            scalarValues[i] = (float)Math.pow(.80,i);
                            scalarValuesNEXT[i] = scalarValues[i]*.95f ;
                        }



                        cosValues = new float[bufferSize/4] ;
                        sinValues = new float[bufferSize/4] ;
                            for (int i = 0 ;  i < bufferSize/4 ; i++) {
                                cosValues[i] =  (float)Math.cos(deltaAngle*i) ;
                                sinValues[i] =  (float)Math.sin(deltaAngle*i) ;
                            }

                    }


                    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
                    {

                            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

                             height = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().top/2 ;
                             width = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().left/2 ;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
                    {

                            this.visible = visible;
                            if (visible) 
                            {
                                handler.post(drawRunner);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                              releaseAudio() ;
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
                    {

                            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
                            this.visible = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
                    {

                            draw();
                    }


                    short[] buffer ;
                    void draw() 
                    {

                        buffer = new short[bufferSize] ;

                        if (recorder != null) {
                        bufferSize = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                        } else {
                            // need to get recorder
                            captureAudio() ;
                            bufferSize = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                        }


                            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

                            Canvas c = null;
                            try 
                            {
                                    c = holder.lockCanvas();
                                    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    if (c != null)
                                    {



                                            float total = 0 ;

                                            float currentRadii[] = new float[size] ;  
                                            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                                            {
                                            currentRadii[i] = buffer[i]*exagger+defaultRaduiis ;

                                            total += Math.abs(buffer[i]) ;
                                            }
                                            total /= (size) ;

                                            int currentColor = (int)(colordelemiter*total) ;

                                            pastRadii.add(currentRadii) ;
                                            circleEmphasis.add(currentColor) ;


                                            float scalarRad  ;
                                            float scalarRadPlus ;
                                            float rad[]= new float [size];

                                            colorMult = 205 / (on+1) ;
                                                    for (int i = on ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {

                                                           rad = pastRadii.get(i) ;
                                                           p.setARGB(255, circleEmphasis.get(i), 0, colorMult*i+50) ;
                                                           p.setStrokeWidth((float) (scalarValues[i]*10f+1f)) ;
                                                              for(int f = 0; f < size-2; f+=2)
                                                          {
                                                                  scalarRad = rad[f]*scalarValues[i];
                                                                  //if
                                                                  scalarRadPlus = rad[f+1]*scalarValues[i] ;

                                                            c.drawLine(cosValues[f]*scalarRad + width, sinValues[f]*scalarRad + height, cosValues[f+1]*scalarRadPlus + width, sinValues[f+1]*scalarRadPlus + height, p)  ;
                                                          }
                                                              c.drawLine(cosValues[size-2]*rad[size-2]*scalarValues[i] + width, sinValues[size-2]*rad[size-2]*scalarValues[i] + height, cosValues[0]*rad[0]*scalarValues[i] + width, sinValues[0]*rad[0]*scalarValues[i] + height, p)  ;
                                                          } 


                                                  if (pastRadii.size() >= circleNum) {
                                                    pastRadii.remove(0) ;
                                                    circleEmphasis.remove(0) ;
                                                  }      
                                    }
                             }
                            finally 
                            {
                            if (c != null)
                            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }

                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                            if (visible) 
                            {
                            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10);
                            }

                    }
            }
```

}

This is my .xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/wallpaper_description"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     android:permission="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO">

    <service
        android:name="com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper.AudioWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="Audio Wallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"

         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" >
        </meta-data>
    </service>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Restart eclipse and try again, if that doesn't work make new project in eclipse and copy/paste source.

Comment: I already tried that, I even used multiple computers and installations of eclipse.

Comment: Tried that also, didn't change the error.

Comment: `at com.johntcompas.audio_live_wallpaper.AudioWallpaperService.<init>(AudioWallpaperService.java:37)`
What the code at this line?

Comment: Looking at similar errors about this, it seems like people were having problems with their instantiation of their Service class, but I can't find anything wrong with mine.

Comment: defaultRaduiis = 850 ; - Nothing special

Comment: It's inside my OnCreate() method